# "s'accrocher à son rêve" and "se raccrocher à son rêve" - what's the difference?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, préfixes

I think normally the prefix "r(e)" changes somewhat the meaning of a verb but in this case both seem to have the same meaning, figuratively used.

Answer (score 6):

"S'accrocher" means "holding fast, not giving up". "Se raccrocher" is more negative, a plan B: when things go wrong you focus on your dreams as your lifejacket.